# Cannot save iTunes library

Tags: windows-7, itunes

Ever since I began using Windows 7 x64, I have been getting an infrequent error when using iTunes which goes something like this:

```
The iTunes Library file cannot be saved. You do not have enough access privileges for this operation.
```

Up until today this seemed to have no bad side effect but today I got the error, exited iTunes and started it back up only to discover my entire library was empty (the .xml file seemed to have been initialized).

While I can restore my library from backup, this is pretty frustrating. Enough so that I may move the library to a MAC and sync there.

I have reset the permissions on the folder. I have excluded the file from anti-virus scan. Neither of these things helped.

EDIT:

- The directory location is the default c:\users\username\Music\iTunes
- No directories where moved in this install.
- It is a clean install of Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Are you using the default user directory setup?  Have you moved your directories around?  Did you do a clean install or upgrade of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resolved this by excluding the entire folder from my anti-virus. I use NOD32 and I found more than a few posts out there indicating that there was an issue between the two. For example:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2312233&tstart=90